# How to prevent NSToolbar overlapping NSViewController content?

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar

I have a basic MacOS app with a toolbar and a view controller. I'm trying to perform some layout without constraints but when I try to position a subview in the top left corner it gets hidden under the toolbar.

Here's an example to demonstrate the problem (this just requires a default MacOS app with a storyboard). I've added -10 to the y position so the label peeks out.

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let label = NSTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(label)
        label.stringValue = "My Label"
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        super.viewDidLayout()

        label.sizeToFit()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                             y: view.bounds.maxY - 10,
                             width: label.bounds.width,
                             height: label.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong please? Is there a way to tell the toolbar to sit above the view controller's content rather that overlapping it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the content after the view did appear?

Comment: I don't think that'll make a different. This is just an example illustrating the issue. In reality I'm doing layout in a custom view which is pinned to the superview edges of the view controller's view and the problem still persists.

Comment: If you say so...  But your application doesn't know the true view height until the toolbar appears, which your view controller only knows about when the view did appear.

Comment: `label.frame.y` is the bottom of the label and its height > 10. is "Full Size Content View" of the window switched on? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke You've nailed it with `label.frame.y` being the bottom of the label. I'm an iOS background where the origin is top left! If you reply as an answer I can accept it. Btw, how is what I've provided not a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: The Xcode project in my version of Xcode doesn't have a toolbar. I was wondering what the window and toolbar settings are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label.frame.y` is the bottom of the label and its height > 10.

```
label.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                     y: view.bounds.maxY - label.frame.height,
                     width: label.frame.width,
                     height: label.frame.height)
```